# Use Google Search Appliance Test center as my own aspx page

Tags: asp.net, google-search-appliance

How would I use the view google has in the test center (where i test my frontend)?

When a user browse to site/search.aspx I want the to get the view testcenter shows, searchboxes and everything. I would also like to add my own javascript and css to the page.
Is this possible?

Now I have created a search box with updatepanel to show the results but this approach will force me to do a lot of parsing and setting variables for the dynamic navigation. I.e. a lot of logic Google already serves in test center.

By the way, I dont want to use the McA+ library supporting GSA 6.14.

Comment: wht do u mean...? You need the google like search functionality? while entering on the textbox u have to get the result in the datalist?

Comment: No, we have a Google Search Appliance. Liek this one. http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/

Comment: You can customize the XSLT to look like the view from the test center. If you enable Dynamic Navigation for the front end, then the XSLT will already have the necessary parsing logic within. My suggestion would be - send the request to GSA without the proxystylesheet parameter, then GSA would return the results in XML format. Transform this XML using the XSLT however you want.

Comment: @itsbalur Thanks! I ended up serializing the result feeding a repeater with basic C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I serialized the xml result from the GSA to C# objects and then fed them to my frontend where I could handle them.

Comment: Have you written the C# classes by hand or generated them somehow?

Comment: @Kniganapolke I used a command line program to convert the xml to classes. Since June this functionality is available in Visual Studio. Go to a .cs class-> vlick EDIT-> Paste Special->"Paste XML As Classes" and visual studio will take the copied ML and paste as classes.

Answer (score 0):

Example of converting XML to HTML using XSL in C# ASP.NET can be found at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469723/Rendering-XML-Data-as-HTML-using-XSL-Transformatio